# NullPointer for socket receive or maybe the socket

Tags: java, android, networking, udp, wifi

I've been sending packets to clients connected to the server fine, but trying to
send the same packet to the actual host itself keeps coming up with an error.

Here is the code that breaks

```
if(socket == null)
            {
                try 
                {
                    socket = new DatagramSocket( port );
                } 
                catch (SocketException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if( server.returnPlayers() > 0)
            {

                byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length );
                try 
                {
                    socket.receive( packet ); ..<---this line
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error with receiving data");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ...
```

Any idea why? the same packet is sent to the clients, and it works 100%.

Canvas

Comment: is it possible that your socket = new DatagramSocket( port ); call failed before that? youre just printing the stack trace in that case, and continuing execution

Answer (score 0):

Your try/catch is too local It is possible for 'socket' to be still null after the catch. Move the catch to the end of this code. Don't catch exceptions until after the code that can be affected by them.